# Restful Service in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, rest

Apart from using ADO.NET Data Services or WCF Services,When i want to use RESTful services in ASP.NET (consider if i want to use it ASP.NET 2.0), do i need to download any specific API inorder to use Rest Webservice.If so,where can i download the same?

Answer (score 2):

If there is *any* possible way to upgrade to .NET 3.5, then I highly recommend that you do that and use ASP.NET MVC.  It's built to handle a good number of things you would have to build from the ground up (the most important being path mapping) and it will save you a tremendous amount of time.

While it could be done in ASP.NET in .NET 2.0, it just isn't practical given the amount of work involved and the fact that it's already done for you in a later version of the framework.

Comment: Thank for the info.I will upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio magazine](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2006/09/01/build-restful-aspnet-apps.aspx) did a decent article on how this could be accomplished in native ASP.NET 2.0.

I read over it briefly a while ago and it was a good overview of how you could do it without any external dependencies.